# Column must appear in the GROUP BY clause error even though it DOES appear there

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have a table that looks like this:

```
order_number | key_a | key_b | key_c | key_d | quantity
-------------|-------|-------|-------|------------------
14400        | 2     | 3     | 4     |    54 | 40
14000        | 2     | 3     | 4     |    87 | 13
```

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
select order_number,key_a,key_b,key_c,sum(quantity) from my_table
      group by (order_number,key_a,key_b,key_c);
```

Yet I'm getting the error:

```
 ERROR:   column "my_table.order_number" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Since the column very clearly ***IS*** present in the GROUP BY clause,
I am very confused.

I also tried explicitly naming the column as `my_table.order_number` as shown in the error message, but no dice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. It's the damn *parentheses* around the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause. The correct query is:

```
select order_number,key_a,key_b,key_c,sum(quantity) from my_table
      group by order_number,key_a,key_b,key_c;
```